# Can you use MSpec's "Tags" attribute with TFS Build?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, vstest, mspec

My team writes unit and integration tests for each service we write.  I am trying to use MSpec's [Tags("CIOnly")] attribute which I thought was supposed to behave similar to the [TestCategory] attribute for MSTest so we can filter out only tests with the CIOnly attribute but I'm not 100% sure how to get these tags to work correctly with our CI Builds in TFS.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  I've tried /TestCaseFilter:Tags="CIOnly" but it doesn't appear to be filtering correctly.

Comment: Looks like this is currently not supported: https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/issues/327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you use MSpec's “Tags” attribute with TFS Build?

I am afraid you can do this at this moment.

Just like jessehouwing pointed, this TestCaseFilter is not supported by MSpec now, which is scheduled for milestone 2.0.0:

https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/pull/352

You can track this thread and check the feedback.

Hope this helps.